# ffmpeg - create a morph video between 2 images (png solid hex color) 0.55 seconds for a length of 10 seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, imagick

currently i create with imagick (convert -size 640x480 xc:#FF000 hex1.png and hex2.png) 2 png images and save both png files.

now i need the following (but i have no idea how i can do that (maybe ffmpeg?)):

create a video 640x480 for example a length of 10 seconds like this method:
0.00s (hex1) > 0.55s (hex2) > 1.10s (hex1) > 1.65s (hex2) > 2.2s (hex1).... until the 10 seconds has reached.

the hex1 and hex2 images should always morph/fade from hex1 => hex2 => hex1, ...

but the time is very critical. the time must be exact always have 0.55.

maybe i can create on same way direct the HEX colors without creating first a png image for that purposes.

can anybody helps me how i can do that best way?

thank you so much and many greets iceget

currently i have created only a single image with that function:
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i hex1.png -c:v libx264 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4

Comment: Try the [`xfade` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade). linked doc has an example

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the approaches to achieving your goal without pre-creation of images:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y \
  -f lavfi -i color=c=0x0000ff:size=640x480:duration=0.55:rate=20 \
  -filter_complex \
    "[0]fade=type=out:duration=0.55:color=0xffff00[fade_first_color]; \
    [fade_first_color]split[fade_first_color1][fade_first_color2]; \
    [fade_first_color1]reverse[fade_second_color]; \
    [fade_first_color2][fade_second_color]concat[fade_cycle]; \
    [fade_cycle]loop=loop=10/(0.55*2):size=0.55*2*20,trim=duration=10" \
  flicker.mp4
```

Since `loop` filter operates with frames, not seconds, and you have time constraints, you may choose only the few FPS rates correspondig to the integer number of frames that fit in the 0.55 seconds period (e.g. 20, 40, 60).

The filtergraph is self-explanable.

The result of such command will be like this:

[image: flicker]

**Almost universal way** (added in response to the OP's new questions)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Input parameters
color_1=0x0000ff
color_2=0xffff00
segment_duration=0.55
total_duration=10

# Magic calculations
sd_numerator=${segment_duration#*.}
sd_denominator=$(( 10**${#sd_numerator} ))
FPS=$(ffprobe -v error -f lavfi "aevalsrc=print('$sd_denominator/gcd($sd_numerator,$sd_denominator)'\,16):s=1:d=1" 2>&1)
FPS=${FPS%.*}

# Preparing the output a little bit longer than total_duration
# and mark the cut point with the forced keyframe
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y \
  -f lavfi -i color=c=$color_1:size=640x480:duration=$segment_duration:rate=$FPS \
  -filter_complex \
    "[0]fade=type=out:duration=$segment_duration:color=$color_2[fade_first_color]; \
     [fade_first_color]split[fade_first_color1][fade_first_color2]; \
     [fade_first_color1]reverse[fade_second_color]; \
     [fade_first_color2][fade_second_color]concat[fade_cycle]; \
     [fade_cycle]loop=loop=ceil($total_duration/($segment_duration*2))+1: \
                      size=$segment_duration*2*$FPS,fps=fps=25" \
  -force_key_frames $total_duration \
  flicker_temp.mp4

# Fine cut of total_duration
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i flicker_temp.mp4 -to $total_duration flicker_${total_duration}s.mp4

# Clean up
rm flicker_temp.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This seems the best way without using imagick. Thank you!

Two questions:
1) When i now want using 49 Seconds (with the same code) then the MP4 file is only 48 Seconds long. But i need the exact 49 Seconds. Is there a possibility to set the duration exact to 49 seconds?

2) And how to calculate the FPS rates when i want use 0.2225 rather 0.55? How i can canculate that correctly? 

Thank you so much!

Comment: have tried that with this command: ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -f lavfi -i color=c=0x0000ff:size=640x480:duration=0.55:rate=20 -filter_complex "[0]fade=type=out:duration=0.55:color=0xffff00[fade_first_color]; [fade_first_color]split[fade_first_color1][fade_first_color2];[fade_first_color1]reverse[fade_second_color]; [fade_first_color2][fade_second_color]concat[fade_cycle];[fade_cycle]loop=loop=49/(0.55*2):size=0.55*2*20,trim=duration=49" tmp/test.mp4.

but get here back this time for the video: time=00:00:48.30.

is there a possibility to set the exact lenght for that video? thank you so much

Comment: @iceget 1) It's possible with two ffmpeg's runs (see updated answer). 2) You may use greatest common divisor (see updated answer).